# jQuery Remotipart sending [object Object] to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to upload a file to my Rails application with ajax. To facilitate this, I have included the [jQuery.remotipart gem](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart).

```
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery.remotipart
```

I have a form for uploading files. These files are processed by CarrierWave.

```
<%= form_for @import, remote: true do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <%= f.label :file, "Attach a CSV file" %>
    <%= f.file_field :file %>
  </fieldset>
  <%= f.submit :upload %>

<% end -%>
```

Unfortunately, when I submit the form with a file attached, it doesn't seem to arrive at my controller action correctly. The params hash has stringified JS objects as keys.

```
Started POST "/file_imports" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-06 01:00:49 +0000
Processing by FileImportsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"object Object"=>{","=>{"object Object"=>{","=>{"object Object"=>nil}}}}}`
```

In Chrome's Dev Tools, I can see that this is indeed the form data that is being sent to the server:

[image: Form data being sent to server]

The form works perfectly when I remove `remote: true` (of course, it sends a HTML request rather than a JS request in that case).

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? By the way I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and Remotipart 1.0.2 (latest).

**Edit:** Did some more digging.

Looking into the Remotipart source, I can't seem to understand what it is supposed to do. For example, in [`vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.remotipart.js`](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.remotipart.js#L22), Line 22 has the following:

```
settings.data = form.serializeArray();
```

A little further down, the settings are sent to the server via `$.rails.ajax(settings)`.

The `$.fn.serializeArray()` method returns an array of JS objects. If we assign them to the data attribute of a call to `jQuery.ajax()`, that would account for the serialized object parameters I'm seeing on the server. We need to pass an object as the data attribute, not an array of objects?

However, when I try to flatten the array into one object, the whole thing breaks and a HTML request is sent to the server instead of a JS one. I think it has something to do with the fact that `jQuery.ajax.processData == false`.

I have an [issue on the Remotipart Github](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/issues/48).

Comment: The params seem really whacked.  Are you sure all the pre-requisite javascript is loaded?  also you don't need all that path in the manifest,  application.js alone should be fine.

Comment: That comment in the manifest isn't actually there, I just wanted to indicate which file of the app the `//= require jquery.manifest` is located in. Apologies for the confusion. I'm sure I'm requiring everything. I have `jquery` then `jquery_ujs` then `jquery.remotipart` in that order.

Comment: no problemo.  Everything looks correct.  You say in your original post 'a file',  but remotipart is all about 'multipart' uploads.  Have you thought about removing 'remotipart' gem and just trying to get basic file upload working with a 'single' file upload?  THEN, once you understand the basic mechanics of a single file upload,  then introduce 'remoteipart' to deal with multiple file uploads in the same post?

Comment: Yeah I should probably mention it in the question but if I remove the `remote: true` from the form then it works fine (only with a HTML request rather than JS). I can't see anything on the Remotipart Github which would suggest that it shouldn't work for singular uploads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a ton of debugging and reading through lots of code, I finally have the latest gem working with Rails 3.2.8. I was nailed by three gotchas:

(1) I was disabling my file input field prior to form submission and this causes remotipart to ignore it for inclusion in the iframe submission. You must make sure your file inputs are enabled. This is the direct cause of the bug you are seeing.

(2) In the course of my debugging, I was overriding `jquery.iframe-transport` with the latest upstream source and it doesn't have support for the `X-Http-Accepts` hidden variable in the iframe. You must use the version bundled with the remotipart gem.

(3) Don't forget to wire up a callback for ajax:complete on the form if you are using a datatype other than `script`. This is the default if you don't specify dataType in the global ajax options, or use the data-type attribute on the form.

Comment: Overriding jquery.iframe-transport was the source of my problems too. Thanks for figuring this out Matt.