# Posting form between 2 rails applications including files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, cors

I am trying to post a form from one rails app to another hosted on different domains and including files.

I attempted:

```
$(document).on("click", ".application-form .submission input", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(".application-form form");
    var data = new FormData(form);
    var url = "http://example.com/action";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(){
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
        },
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

But the remote server doesn't receive any data, params merely contains the controller name and action.

I also have tried using remotipart and setting up my form with `form_for(@application, url: "http://example.com/action", html: {multipart: true}, remote: true)` and if I include a file, the server receives `[object Object]` instead of correct param names and values.  If I do not include a file, then the params are sent and received correctly, but I need to include files with the upload.

What is going on to cause `[object Object]` to replace all my form data when I include a file?  Using remotipart 1.2.1.  And I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242988/jquery-remotipart-sending-object-object-to-server) and it does not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with attempting what you are:

1. Cross Domain Requests ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing))
2. Form
3. Uploading

---

**CORS**

Your first issue is you have to ensure you're able to pass the data between the two domains. CORS is a standard protocol, whereby you can only send requests to pre-approved domains

Basically, you need some way to whitelist the possible connecting domains, and with Rails, you'll be best to use the [RACK-CORS](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem

I would begin by ensuring this is set up on your "receiving" domain

---

**Form**

Secondly, you need to compile the correct form data when you submit

I would use the [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function:

```
$(document).on("click", ".application-form .submission input", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(".application-form form");
    var data = form.serialize();
    var url = "http://example.com/action";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(){
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
        },
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

This will probably explain the lack of params being sent to your other domain

---

**Upload**

Uploading files creates a totally new issue, as it takes a lot to get the file-upload process to work through ajax

There are plugins such as [JQuery-FileUpload-Rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) allow you to upload files through ajax. From my understanding, this works by providing custom middleware to handle the file upload over ajax. I'm not totally sure how it works, but I know it does, as we've used t multiple times

Comment: I'll go ahead and accept this. I've already enabled CORS on both servers, and serialize() won't send files unlike FormData(). And I did use the same middleware as that plugin, but it wouldn't send both normal form data (strings) and files, only one or the other, unless I was posting to the same domain for some reason..hence the question. What I ended up doing is just posting from the backend in an after_save callback though.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot directly upload files from a form via AJAX. You have to 'fake' it using either a hidden iframe, Flash, or something similar (might be different in the newest browsers). The jQuery Form plugin does a good job of simplifying this, and there are lots of other plugins as well to help with this.

Comment: Well, you're supposed to be able to by using FormData in XHR2, but the receiving server just gets a blank POST, there's no data received. And remotipart uses an iframe through jquery.iframe-transport.  But specifying a remote server results in [object Object] being sent instead of my data.

Comment: Also having this problem with Remotipart, the answer ignores his question since aperture was asking about the Object object response in Remotipart, which uses an iFrame workaround.